# django put data table in model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

(A Django rookie here)

For a "project" model I want to store some data. The data is about housing property. So, for example: Number of living spaces, on which floor those spaces are, and how big those spaces are.

- Living-space 1 - Groundfloor - 50m2
- Living-space 2 - First floor - 82m2
- etc.

Because not every project object has the some amount of living spaces and some project object's also have a row called something like Shop-space or restaurant space I was wondering about a good approach to storing this data. 
**B**asically I want to store a dynamically sized table in a model. Below is pretty good example:

- Restaurant - Groundfloor - 147m2
- Livingspace 1 - First floor - 55m2
- Livingspace 2 - First floor - 110m2
- Livingspace 3 - Second floor - 55m2
- Livingspace 4 - Second floor - 110m2
- Livingspace 5 - Third floor - 147m2

Now some projects will have only 2 maybe 3 living spaces and no Restaurant's etc. Others will have maybe up to 10 living spaces. I was thinking about creating 10 row fields. So I can put in comma separated values (or maybe JSONfield). Something like:

```
row_01 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
row_02 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
row_03 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
row_etc = models.CharField(max_length=100)

"Livingspace 1","First floor","55"
"Livingspace 2","Second floor","100"
etc
```

1. Would this be a correct approach for putting this table in the database? How about a JSONfield?
2. Also, in my model I have a field in which the number of housing-spaces has to be put in by the user. Therefore I was thinking if it's possible to dynamically create rows based on other fields in the model? So if the user is in the Django administration and enters 4 for the number of houses that the user only sees 4 rows in the Django administration.

Comment: please show your current models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not good practice.

From what I understand, the data can be included using two tables. In django, each model corresponds to a table, with fields as columns. So you just have to make a House model and another model Room with Foreign key relationship to the House model.

A simple example:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Room(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House)
    room_type = models.CharField()
    area = models.CharField()
    floor_no = models.IntegerField()
```

From this, each House model instance represents a house. Each Room instance represents the row you said earlier. By designing the models like this could make the filtering, querying​ very easy.

Room instances are linked to the House model through a foreign key relationship, which enables to create any number of rows according to the required specifications.

For more reference, try the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

Comment: tnx! This is what you call a many-to-one relationship, correct? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: yes that's right. are you satisfied with this answer?

Comment: Yes, i've been trying this out and from a technical perspective this should be the best answer. However, from the end-user perspective, I'm not so happy with the way this works in combination with the Django administration. With a lot of houses, and a lot floors per house, you get a lot of entries in the admin page. I guess the Django admin isn't perfect for this. :(

Comment: Actually, the list_filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) solves this by giving the user the option to select only a certain house. Makes it a lot more organized!

Comment: Actually actually, when using InlineModel, list_display, list_editable, ordering, etc cetera, the Django admin becomes a very capable back-end! Love it :-)

Answer (score 0):

The kind of db schema depends on how you are going to use that data.
The fields (except primary key) who you want to **aggregate** (sum,count etc) , **querying** based on them will be directly placed as a column while fields that are dependent(dynamicity) on other columns can be come into JSON field.

Considering your use case , JSON Field can be a good approach because you might not want to query based on each and every data .